# How do i make ES aggregation to work on the output of a function_score query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a function_score query and i want to apply top_hit aggregation on the output of my function_score query, as such i am using function_score query to filter parents based child properties, then i want to run some queries over those parents via the aggregation and then sort them accordingly.

Query:

```
POST test/_search?size=0
{
"query": {
"function_score": {
  "query": {
    "match_all" : {}
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "has_child": {
                "type": "track",
                "query": {
                  "exists": {
                    "field": "url"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "weight": 5
    }
  ]
}
},
"aggs": {
"top_tags": {
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "common_info.CD.Handle"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase" : {
            "common_info.CD.device" : "D/C"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "test_agg_on_doc": {
      "top_hits": {
        "sort" : [

        ],
        "_source": {
          "includes": [
            "common_info.CD.Handle"  
          ]
        },
        "size": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

When i run this query my function_score query is not getting considered at all as such and "aggs" are working on the total number of docs, but i want it to run on the docs that are filtered using function_score query. Any help would be highly appreciated. thanks